# NA filling only if "sandwiched" by the same value using dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, na

Ok, here is yet another missing value filling question.

I am looking for a way to fill NAs based on both the previous and next existent values in a column. Standard filling in a single direction is not sufficient for this task.

If the previous and next valid values in a column are not the same, then the chunk remains as NA.

[image]

The code for the sample data frame is:

```
df_in <- tibble(id= 1:12,
        var1 = letters[1:12],
        var2 = c(NA,rep("A",2),rep(NA,2),rep("A",2),rep(NA,2),rep("B",2),NA))
```

Thanks,

Comment: *"If the previous and next valid values in a column are not the same, then the chunk remains as NA."* Based on your rule, I don't see how rows 4 and 5 get filled. In row 4 the previous value is `A` and the next value `NA`. Therefore it should stay `NA`. Similarly for row 5. Could you please clarify?

Comment: @MauritsEvers I think 'valid' should be interpreted as 'not `NA`' here.

Comment: @Florian Hmm, yes I think you're right:-)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Comparing `na.locf()` (last observation carried forward) and `na.locf(fromLast = TRUE)` (backward):

```
mutate(df_in, 
       var_new = if_else(
         zoo::na.locf(var2, na.rm = FALSE) == 
           zoo::na.locf(var2, na.rm = FALSE, fromLast = TRUE),
         zoo::na.locf(var2, na.rm = FALSE),
         NA_character_
       ))

# # A tibble: 12 x 4
#       id var1  var2  var_new
#    <int> <chr> <chr> <chr>  
#  1     1 a     NA    NA     
#  2     2 b     A     A      
#  3     3 c     A     A      
#  4     4 d     NA    A      
#  5     5 e     NA    A      
#  6     6 f     A     A      
#  7     7 g     A     A      
#  8     8 h     NA    NA     
#  9     9 i     NA    NA     
# 10    10 j     B     B      
# 11    11 k     B     B      
# 12    12 l     NA    NA
```

Comment: Quick follow up question (and slightly unrelated): I noticed that if the mutate is applied to the original variable "var2", a simple `NA` is sufficient at the end of the `if_else` statement. Why is `NA_character_` required instead of plain `NA` at the end of the `if_else` statement when mutating to a new variable?

Comment: For me it doesn't matter if I assign to `var2` or `var_new`, I get an error with just `NA`, because `dplyr::if_else()` (with an `_`) does type checking. But note I've edited my answer and had originally used `base::ifelse` (no `_`), that doesn't check type and does coercion afterwards

Answer (score 2):

Something like this?

```
df_in %>% mutate(var_new = {
       tmp <- var2
       tmp[is.na(tmp)] <- "NA"
       rl <- rle(tmp)
       tibble(before = c(NA, head(rl$values, -1)),
              value  = rl$values,
              after  = c(tail(rl$values, -1), NA),
              lengths = rl$lengths) %>%
       mutate(value = ifelse(value == "NA" & before == after, before, value),
              value = ifelse(value == "NA", NA, value)) %>%
       select(value, lengths) %>%
       unname() %>%
       do.call(rep, .)})

# # A tibble: 12 x 4
#       id var1  var2  var_new
#    <int> <chr> <chr> <chr>  
#  1     1 a     NA    <NA>   
#  2     2 b     A     A      
#  3     3 c     A     A      
#  4     4 d     NA    A      
#  5     5 e     NA    A      
#  6     6 f     A     A      
#  7     7 g     A     A      
#  8     8 h     NA    <NA>   
#  9     9 i     NA    <NA>   
# 10    10 j     B     B      
# 11    11 k     B     B      
# 12    12 l     NA    <NA>
```

**Explanation**

1. Convert `NA` to `"NA"` (because `rle` does not count consecutive `NA`.)
2. Create a run length encoded representation of `tmp`
3. Now you cna have a look at values beofre and after the relevant blocks
4. Replace the values.

Comment: I get the same values for `var_new` as for `var2`. Nothing seems to get filled. Can you double-check?

Comment: Sorry forget a line from my code, is updated now. Basically you need to transform `NA` to `"NA"` because `rle` does not count consecutive `NA` but treats them as distinct values

Comment: Nice one @thothal +1