# Filling missing only if "sandwiched" by the same value

Tags: stata, missing-data

I have seen questions for this in R and Python (e.g., [NA filling only if "sandwiched" by the same value using dplyr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51704128/na-filling-only-if-sandwiched-by-the-same-value-using-dplyr)), but can't find an answer of how to do this in Stata.

I would like to fill in missing values in a panel dataset ONLY if it is in between 2 equal non-missing values. For example, if I have

```
clear 
input score group
2005 1
2006 .
2007 .
2008 .
2009 1
2010 8
2011 1
2012 .
2013 5
2014 3
2015 4
end
```

the missing observations in 2006, 2007, and 2008 would be filled in to become 1, but the missing observation in 2012 would not be filled in. The missing values are categorical and not ordinal.

I have tried filling in with the prior value if the prior value and next value are equal, but this doesn't account for situations where there are more than 1 missing sandwiched between two equal non-missing values.

Edit: The solution provided below works in some cases but acts unexpectedly in others (I've changed some of the variable names to make it more intuitive and to include two examples in one block). Suppose I start with

```
clear 
input year group id
2005 1 1
2006 1 .
2007 1 .
2008 1 .
2009 1 .
2010 1 .
2011 1 1
2007 2 3
2008 2 .
2009 2 .
2010 2 2
2011 2 2
end
```

Using the solution, sometimes I get

```
clear 
input year group id
2005 1 1
2006 1 .
2007 1 .
2008 1 .
2009 1 .
2010 1 .
2011 1 1
2007 2 3
2008 2 3
2009 2 3
2010 2 2
2011 2 2
end
```

For group 1, the non-missings do not fill in when they should. For group 2, they do fill in but should not because the non-missing values at the ends of the sandwich are not equal.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to do it.

1. One method of interpolation or imputation is just to carry the last known value forward. In Stata this is discussed at https://www.stata.com/support/faqs/data-management/replacing-missing-values/
2. Another method is linear interpolation. Linear interpolation will produce the same answer as method 1 if, and only if, the interpolation is flat, so that interpolated values equal known values at each end.

No doubt you could just interpolate and check for constancy, but my guess is that would be about as much code as is given here.

```
clear 
input score group
2005 1
2006 .
2007 .
2008 .
2009 1
2010 8
2011 1
2012 .
2013 5
2014 3
2015 4
end

clonevar guess1 = group 
replace guess1 = guess1[_n-1] if missing(guess1) 

ipolate group score, gen(guess2)

gen goodguess = guess1 if guess1 == guess2 

list, sepby(goodguess)

     +--------------------------------------------+
     | score   group   guess1   guess2   goodgu~s |
     |--------------------------------------------|
  1. |  2005       1        1        1          1 |
  2. |  2006       .        1        1          1 |
  3. |  2007       .        1        1          1 |
  4. |  2008       .        1        1          1 |
  5. |  2009       1        1        1          1 |
     |--------------------------------------------|
  6. |  2010       8        8        8          8 |
     |--------------------------------------------|
  7. |  2011       1        1        1          1 |
     |--------------------------------------------|
  8. |  2012       .        1        3          . |
     |--------------------------------------------|
  9. |  2013       5        5        5          5 |
     |--------------------------------------------|
 10. |  2014       3        3        3          3 |
     |--------------------------------------------|
 11. |  2015       4        4        4          4 |
     +--------------------------------------------+
```

You allude to panel data without exemplifying it, but this method can be extended easily to panel data. Use a `by:` or a `by()` option as needed.

EDIT The late detail that the variable concerned is categorical not ordinal (meaning, nominal not ordinal; many if not most authorities regard "ordinal" as one kind of categorical; witness Alan Agresti's texts) does not affect the solution here. The copying downwards method will never suggest a different category. `ipolate` treats data as if linear interpolation makes sense; when it suggests an unacceptable replacement value, that will not be accepted by the code above.

EDIT 2 You are getting results that you don't want because you are applying code for one problem to quite a different problem. Evidently three variables, not two, are involved, contrary to the initial question.  In that case, the code should be different.

```
clear 
input year group id
2005 1 1
2006 1 .
2007 1 .
2008 1 .
2009 1 .
2010 1 .
2011 1 1
2007 2 3
2008 2 .
2009 2 .
2010 2 2
2011 2 2
end

clonevar guess1 = id 
bysort group (year) : replace guess1 = guess1[_n-1] if missing(guess1) 

ipolate id year, gen(guess2) by(group)

gen goodguess = guess1 if guess1 == guess2
```

Otherwise put, the initial answer worked from the example given in which the observations were in `year` order and there was no grouping variable; hence there was only one observation for each distinct `year`.

When there is other structure (e.g. panel or longitudinal data) you need other code to match it.

Comment: Thank you for the guidance, Nick! When trying this in my dataset, I noticed that goodguess will sometimes 1) fill in missing with the first non-missing value in the group even if it is not equal to the next non-missing value in the group and 2) fail to fill in when the gap of non-missing values is larger (4+). I have not used ipolate before--would you know what could be going on?

Comment: I am also now noticing that apart from missing, there may be 2 years in the middle of a group that is non-missing but a different value (switched groups for just those 2 years) and I would like to assign them the same way as above. I think the idea might be similar to above.

Comment: Please give specific examples—in a revision of your question—of the problems you report—and of what else you want.

Comment: Without examples I see no reason to doubt my code. Otherwise your last comment seems to imply that sometimes you want to use this method and sometimes you don't, which is likely but hard to discuss.

Comment: Thanks, Nick. I haven't been able to figure out the specific characteristics that may be associated with these differences, but I have tried to explain both that and the other similar case above.

Comment: I removed the edit with the case of non-missing but different values.

Comment: I had added the bys group (year), but missed the by(group) in ipolate. Thanks again for your help.