Replacing NA's within a set of similar values
I have a column in a dataset looking like this:
cluster_id
1
1
1
1
NA
1
NA
NA
2
NA
2
NA
3
NA
NA
3


cluster_id <- c("1","1","1","1","NA","1","NA","NA","2","NA","2","NA","3","NA","NA","3")

The order is already pre-defined before using a time column. What I want is to substitute the NA's that are within each cluster ID, i.e. if there's a row with 2, then an NA, and then a 2 again, I want that NA to become 2. The NA's between numbers stay as NA's. Example:
cluster_id   cluster_id_new
1            1
1            1
1            1
1            1
NA           1
1            1
NA           NA
NA           NA
2            2
NA           2
2            2
NA           NA
3            3
NA           3
NA           3
3            3 

I found the zoo::na.locf function in this post, which seems to be close to what I want, but I also need to take in consideration the value after the NA.
Any thoughts?

Great question! Two quick questions: are these values actually characters - i.e., the value actually "NA" (a character value) or NA (missing value) or "1" (character) or 1 (numeric) - and are your data in a single vector like the example, or a data frame?

See if this question is similar https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56134078/replace-na-values-if-last-and-next-non-na-value-are-the-same

How would want to handle leading/trailing NAs?

Update:
thanks to @Darren Tsai (who provided a better version):
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

tibble(cluster_id) %>% 
  mutate(down = cluster_id, up = cluster_id) %>% 
  fill(down, .direction = "down") %>% 
  fill(up, .direction = "up") %>% 
  mutate(cluster_id_new = if_else(down == up, down, NA)) %>% 
  select(-c(down, up))

Original answer:
Here is tidyverse way using mainly fill:
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

tibble(cluster_id) %>%
  mutate(helper = row_number(),
         filldown = fill(., cluster_id, .direction = "down")$cluster_id,
         fillup = fill(., cluster_id, .direction = "up")$cluster_id,
         cluster_id_new = ifelse(filldown == fillup, filldown, NA_real_)) %>%
  select(cluster_id, cluster_id_new)

cluster_id cluster_id_new
        <dbl>          <dbl>
 1          1              1
 2          1              1
 3          1              1
 4          1              1
 5         NA              1
 6          1              1
 7         NA             NA
 8         NA             NA
 9          2              2
10         NA              2
11          2              2
12         NA             NA
13          3              3
14         NA              3
15         NA              3
16          3              3


I have the same idea! Maybe your code can be more readable like this: df %>% mutate(down = cluster_id, up = cluster_id) %>% fill(down, .direction = "down") %>% fill(up, .direction = "up") %>% mutate(cluster_id_new = if_else(down == up, down, NA)) %>% select(-c(down, up))

This works very well, thanks! Hard to choose one as most of them works, but is one might be the "cleanest", so I'll choose this approach

also @DarrenTsai that works too :)

Here is a base R option with rle + cumsum
cluster_id_new <- with(
    rle(cluster_id),
    {
        idx <- values != "NA"
        grp <- cumsum(c(TRUE, head(values[idx], -1) != tail(values[idx], -1)))
        rep(ave(values,
            cummax(replace(idx, which(idx), grp)),
            FUN = \(x) {
                u <- unique(x[x != "NA"])
                if (tail(x, 1) == "NA") {
                    c(rep(u, length(x) - 1), "NA")
                } else {
                    u
                }
            }
        ), lengths)
    }
)

such that
> data.frame(cluster_id, cluster_id_new)
   cluster_id cluster_id_new
1           1              1
2           1              1
3           1              1
4           1              1
5          NA              1
6           1              1
7          NA             NA
8          NA             NA
9           2              2
10         NA              2
11          2              2
12         NA             NA
13          3              3
14         NA              3
15         NA              3
16          3              3


The collapse package has both a na_locf and a na_focb. You could do a pass with each then check for discrepancies.
If your NA values are stored as characters and not NA_character_, you first need to convert to NA_character_.
The solution also depends on how you want to handle leading/trailing "NA"s. The first option keeps them.
cluster_id <- c("NA","1","1","1","NA","1","NA","NA","2","NA","2","NA","3","NA","NA","3","NA")

library(collapse)

i <- which(cluster_id == "NA")
cluster_id[i] <- NA
cluster_id_filled <- na_locf(cluster_id)
cluster_id_filled[-which(cluster_id_filled == na_focb(cluster_id))] <- "NA"
cluster_id[i] <- "NA" # restore the original vector
cluster_id_filled
#>  [1] "NA" "1"  "1"  "1"  "1"  "1"  "NA" "NA" "2"  "2"  "2"  "NA" "3"  "3"  "3"  "3"  "NA"

This second solution uses a single for loop and fills leading/trailing "NA"s.
cluster_id_filled <- cluster_id
j <- 0
for (i in seq_along(cluster_id)) {
  if (cluster_id[i] == "NA") {
    j <- j + 1
  } else if (j != 0) {
    # use `!isFALSE` to handle leading "NA"s
    if (!isFALSE(cluster_id[i] == cluster_id[i - j - 1])) {
      cluster_id_filled[(i - j):(i - 1)] <- cluster_id[i]
    }
    j <- 0
  }
}
# handle trailing "NA"s
if (j != 0) cluster_id_filled[(i - j + 1):i] <- cluster_id_filled[i - j]
cluster_id_filled
#>  [1] "1"  "1"  "1"  "1"  "1"  "1"  "NA" "NA" "2"  "2"  "2"  "NA" "3"  "3"  "3"  "3"  "3"

If your NA values are actually NA, it's a little easier.
cluster_id <- c(NA, 1, 1, 1, 1, NA, 1, NA, NA, 2, NA, 2, NA, 3, NA, NA, 3, NA)
cluster_id_filled <- na_locf(cluster_id)
cluster_id_filled[-which(cluster_id_filled == na_focb(cluster_id))] <- NA
cluster_id_filled
#>  [1] NA  1  1  1  1  1  1 NA NA  2  2  2 NA  3  3  3  3 NA


Brilliant answer! I like your for-loop approach too - very clever

Thanks!! This one worked too, thanks for sharing!

1) na.approx Presumably the cluster id's are integer and it seems they increment by 1 so performing linear interpolation and testing the result for integer is sufficient to determine whether the result should be NA or not.
library(zoo)

x <- cluster_id
a <- na.approx(as.numeric(ifelse(x == "NA", NA, x)), na.rm = FALSE)
data.frame(cluster_id,
           cluster_id_new = ifelse(a == as.integer(a), a, NA)
)

giving:
   cluster_id cluster_id_new
1           1              1
2           1              1
3           1              1
4           1              1
5        <NA>              1
6           1              1
7        <NA>             NA
8        <NA>             NA
9           2              2
10       <NA>              2
11          2              2
12       <NA>             NA
13          3              3
14       <NA>              3
15       <NA>              3
16          3              3

2) na.locf0 If the forward and backward na.locf0 are the same for an NA then it should be replaced.  This is more general since it works directly with the character values and does not assume the id's increase by 1.
library(zoo)

a <- na.locf0(cluster_id)
data.frame(cluster_id,
  cluster_id_new = ifelse(a == na.locf0(cluster_id, fromLast = TRUE), a, NA)
)

Note
cluster_id <- c("1", "1", "1", "1", NA, "1", NA, NA, "2", NA, "2", NA, "3", NA, NA, "3")


I can't think of a 'clever' solution using existing functions that satisfies your criteria; would a for-loop approach work?
cluster_id <- c("1","1","1","1","NA","1","NA","NA","2","NA","2","NA","3","NA","NA","3")
for (i in seq_along(cluster_id[-1])) {
  if(cluster_id[i + 1] == "NA") {
    for(j in (i + 1):length(cluster_id)) {
      if(cluster_id[i] == cluster_id[j]) {
        cluster_id[i + 1] <- cluster_id[j]
      }
    }
  }
}
cluster_id
#>  [1] "1"  "1"  "1"  "1"  "1"  "1"  "NA" "NA" "2"  "2"  "2"  "NA" "3"  "3"  "3" 
#> [16] "3"

Created on 2024-09-27 with reprex v2.1.0

Thanks!! This one worked too, thanks for sharing!
