# Conditionally replace leading and lagging NAs differently, in column by group

Tags: r

I struggle to fill in NAs differently depending on different conditions for first and last non-missing values.
**Background**: People get cataract surgery and change lens status from `phak` to `pseudo`. If the first non-missing value is 'phak', this must have been present in previous not recorded observations. If the last non-missing value is 'pseudo', this can be carried onwards, because the status cannot change back to 'phak'.
One cannot simply use functions like `zoo::na.locf` because if there were NA between a switch, we won't be able to tell at what time exactly the operation was, and those values should remain NA. [Thus, it is not a "sandwich" problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27368770/conditional-na-filling-by-group)

```r
library(tidyverse)

a <- c(NA, 'phak', NA, 'pseudo', NA)
b <- c(NA, 'pseudo', NA, NA, NA)
c <- c('phak', 'phak', NA, NA, NA)

dfoo <- data.frame(a,b,c, stringsAsFactors = FALSE) %>% gather(eye, status)
dfoo
#>      eye status
#> 1      a   <NA>
#> 2      a   phak
#> 3      a   <NA>
#> 4      a pseudo
#> 5      a   <NA>
#> 6      b   <NA>
#> 7      b pseudo
#> 8      b   <NA>
#> 9      b   <NA>
#> 10     b   <NA>
#> 11     c   phak
#> 12     c   phak
#> 13     c   <NA>
#> 14     c   <NA>
#> 15     c   <NA>
```

Desired data frame:

```
#>      eye  status
#> 1      a   phak
#> 2      a   phak
#> 3      a   <NA>
#> 4      a pseudo
#> 5      a pseudo
#> 6      b   <NA>
#> 7      b pseudo
#> 8      b pseudo
#> 9      b pseudo
#> 10     b pseudo
#> 11     c   phak
#> 12     c   phak
#> 13     c   <NA>
#> 14     c   <NA>
#> 15     c   <NA>
```

**The following works for a simple vector**, but I struggle to use this solution within a data frame by group.

```
# by vector:
# first conditionally replace leading NAs
if(a[min(which(!is.na(a)))] == 'phak') {a[1 : min(which(!is.na(a)))] <- 'phak'}
# next conditionally replace last NAs
if(a[max(which(!is.na(a)))] == 'pseudo') {a[max(which(!is.na(a))): length(a)] <- 'pseudo'}

a
#> [1] "phak"   "phak"   NA       "pseudo" "pseudo"
```

<sup>Created on 2019-12-16 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: How do you decide that in case of 5 and 6 that 5 can be pseudo but 6 should indicate the break and not vice versa?

edit: Moreover what about reordering of the column group. Wouldn't this make your intended breaks invalid?

Comment: @Ben373 group column should better be named ID or "eye". These are different IDs, i.e. eyes. Will update accordingly

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a possible tidyverse approach:

1. `group_by` eye levels
2. create two temporary columns `phak` and `pseudo` which respectively replace all `"pseudo"` values and `"phak"` values by `NA`
3. `fill` the `phak` column using `.direction = "up"`
4. `fill` the `pseudo` column using `.direction = "down"`
5. `coalesce` the `phak` and `pseudo` columns back together in the column `status`

```r
library(tidyverse)

dfoo %>%
    group_by(eye) %>%
    mutate(
        phak = na_if(status, "pseudo"),
        pseudo = na_if(status, "phak")
    ) %>%
    fill(phak, .direction = "up") %>%
    fill(pseudo, .direction = "down") %>%
    transmute(status = coalesce(phak, pseudo)) %>%
    ungroup()
#> # A tibble: 15 x 2
#>    eye   status
#>    <chr> <chr> 
#>  1 a     phak  
#>  2 a     phak  
#>  3 a     <NA>  
#>  4 a     pseudo
#>  5 a     pseudo
#>  6 b     <NA>  
#>  7 b     pseudo
#>  8 b     pseudo
#>  9 b     pseudo
#> 10 b     pseudo
#> 11 c     phak  
#> 12 c     phak  
#> 13 c     <NA>  
#> 14 c     <NA>  
#> 15 c     <NA>
```

**Data**

```r
dfoo <- structure(list(eye = c("a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b", 
            "b", "b", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c"), status = c(NA, "phak", NA, 
            "pseudo", NA, NA, "pseudo", NA, NA, NA, "phak", "phak", NA, NA, 
            NA)), row.names = c(NA, -15L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Wow. This took me a few minutes to work out. Beautiful! Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Here is another approach using a custom function

```
apply_fun <- function(x) {
   inds1 <- which(x == 'phak')
   if(length(inds1) > 0) x[1:min(inds1)] <- 'phak'

   inds2 <- which(x == 'pseudo')
   if(length(inds2) > 0) x[max(inds2):length(x)] <- 'pseudo'
   return(x)
}

library(dplyr)
dfoo %>%  group_by(eye) %>% mutate(status = apply_fun(status))

#  eye   status
#  <chr> <chr> 
# 1 a     phak  
# 2 a     phak  
# 3 a     NA    
# 4 a     pseudo
# 5 a     pseudo
# 6 b     NA    
# 7 b     pseudo
# 8 b     pseudo
# 9 b     pseudo
#10 b     pseudo
#11 c     phak  
#12 c     phak  
#13 c     NA    
#14 c     NA    
#15 c     NA
```

Comment: I actually really like this solution- it gives great flexibility with conditionally replacing/assigning values after given occurrences within `mutate`. I could use it for another situation as well. But I also like the accepted answer a lot, because it was great for the given purpose

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution using if else constructs in a `group_by %>% mutate`. The intermediate variable can be removed afterwards, or the `case_when` rewritten to include them.

```
dfoo %>% 
  group_by(eye) %>% 
  mutate(
    changePhak = if(any(status == "phak", na.rm = TRUE))  row_number() < which(status == "phak")   else FALSE,
    changePseudo = if(any(status == "pseudo", na.rm = TRUE)) row_number() > which(status == "pseudo") else FALSE,
    status = case_when(
      changePhak ~ "phak",
      changePseudo ~ "pseudo",
      TRUE ~ status
    )
  )
```

Comment: Thanks. Gives a warning message, so am not quite sure if this is a stable solution. Works for the given data though. You might be interested in the accepted answer, it's a virtuoso use of `na_if`, `fill` and `coalesce`.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out one way, but this seems somehow not the best solution, especially as I have ten thousands of groups, and this solution kills my computer:

1) Split the data frame first by group
2) use lapply by column :

```r
library(tidyverse)


#desired data frame: 
a <- c(NA, 'phak', NA, 'pseudo', NA)
b <- c(NA, 'pseudo', NA, NA, NA)
c <- c('phak', 'phak', NA, NA, NA)

dfoo <- data.frame(a,b,c, stringsAsFactors = FALSE) %>% gather(eye, status)


bind_rows(
  lapply(split(dfoo, dfoo$eye), function(x) {
    # first conditionally replace leading NAs
    if(x[['status']][min(which(!is.na(x[['status']])))] == 'phak') {x[['status']][1 : min(which(!is.na(x[['status']])))] <- 'phak'}
    # next conditionally replace last NAs
    if(x[['status']][max(which(!is.na(x[['status']])))] == 'pseudo') {x[['status']][max(which(!is.na(x[['status']]))): length(x[['status']])] <- 'pseudo'}
    x$status <- x[['status']]
    x
    }
    )
  )
#>    eye status
#> 1    a   phak
#> 2    a   phak
#> 3    a   <NA>
#> 4    a pseudo
#> 5    a pseudo
#> 6    b   <NA>
#> 7    b pseudo
#> 8    b pseudo
#> 9    b pseudo
#> 10   b pseudo
#> 11   c   phak
#> 12   c   phak
#> 13   c   <NA>
#> 14   c   <NA>
#> 15   c   <NA>
```

<sup>Created on 2019-12-16 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>